# Does a new transaction detach all previous entities?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, ejb

Let's say we have the following piece of code:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String street;
    //getters and setters
}

@Stateless
//@Service
public class UserLogicClass {
    @PersistenceContext
    //@Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void logicOnUser(User user) {
        if(logicOnAddress(user.getAddress()) {
            otherLogicOnUser(user);
        }
    }

    public boolean logicOnAddress(Address address) {
        //
        entityManager.find(address);//address becomes managed
        //
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    //@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void otherLogicOnUser
    //
        entityManager.find(user);/*without annotation, user is not managed and address is managed, but with the transaction annotation is the address still managed?*/
    //
    }
}
```

The question relies in the comment from the last method; I am curios what happens in both Spring case and EJB case. Suppose Spring is configured with JTA transactions and any method called from this class would start a new transaction, just as in EJB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more an issue of JPA. The entityManager is not propagated to the new transaction unless you make it extended:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
//@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Quote from the JPA 2.0 specs:

> A container-managed persistence context may be defined to have either
>   a lifetime that is scoped to a single transaction or an extended
>   lifetime that spans multiple transactions, depending on the
>   PersistenceContextType that is specified when its entity manager is
>   created. This specification refers to such persistence contexts as
>   transaction-scoped persistence contexts and extended persistence
>   contexts respectively.

Comment: So unless the type is set to extended, inside that method, a new entity manager is created, which doesn't have any managed entities?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the `otherLogicOnUser` method a new transaction is created and the persistence context should not be propagated unless you make it extended.

Comment: Use of an extended EntityManager was designed to be used in Stateful EJB's, it is not thread safe, and persistence context collisions can arise if a method using a transaction-scoped EntityManager invokes a method using an extended EntityManager in the same transaction.

Answer (score 4):

> Note: Since this mechanism is based on proxies, only 'external' method
>   calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that
>   'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some
>   other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction
>   at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!

otherLogicOnUser() is invoked inside target object.

Read more: [EJB Transactions in local method-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427452/ejb-transactions-in-local-method-calls)