# @TransactionAttribute within the same class methods

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jta

For the given class bellow, why the transaction scope is the same from the caller method ? And why it only works when i call, for example `someBeanInstance.A()` from another class ?

```
@Stateless
public class X {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void A() {
        B();
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    //or @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void B() {
        // here the transaction is the same
        // the annotation has no effect
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to refactor or use AspectJ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo?rq=1

Comment: Im not using Spring, just pure Java EE.

Comment: Then you probably don't have the AspectJ option. The problem with proxies seems to be the same, at least it was in 2009: http://stackoverflow.com/a/427582/14955 Calls on `this` won't get the EJB goodies.

Comment: The link was very helpful, thanks. Do you know some workaround for this case ? It would be awful  create separated classes  just to be proxied on every call

Comment: In that link, they say "the fix is to either inject a reference to the same object (for stateless or singleton), or to use SessionContext.getEJBLocalObject, getEJBObject, or getBusinessObject (possibly with getInvokedBusinessInterface) to get a proxy to the current object."