# Does new transaction starts when method b() is called from method a()?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

Does new transaction starts when method b() is called from method a()?
Or this is just a method call from the object and annotation does not work?
If so, how to do that transaction started?

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void a() {
        b();
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void b() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is depend on what library/framework you use. In plane java of course not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EJB Transactions in local method-calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427452/ejb-transactions-in-local-method-calls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check that by querying the current transaction status using the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` resource. Here is an example i tried on Wildfly 8.1:

1 - Inject the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry as resource:

```
@Resource
TransactionSynchronizationRegistry txReg;
```

2 - a small helper to query the current tranaaction status and return a human readable String:

```
private String getTXStatus()
{
    int txStatus = this.txReg.getTransactionStatus();
    switch (txStatus)
    {
        case Status.STATUS_ACTIVE:
            return "STATUS_ACTIVE";
        case Status.STATUS_COMMITTED:
            return "STATUS_COMMITTED";

        case Status.STATUS_COMMITTING:
            return "STATUS_COMMITTING";
        case Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK:
            return "STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK";
        case Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION:
            return "STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION";
        case Status.STATUS_PREPARED:
            return "STATUS_PREPARED";
        case Status.STATUS_PREPARING:
            return "STATUS_PREPARING";
        case Status.STATUS_ROLLEDBACK:
            return "STATUS_ROLLEDBACK";
        case Status.STATUS_ROLLING_BACK:
            return "STATUS_ROLLING_BACK";
        case Status.STATUS_UNKNOWN:
            return "STATUS_UNKNOWN";
        default:
            return "Unknown(" + txStatus + ")";
    }
```

3 - now you may instrument your business methods with some quick and dirty logging (and NEVER put `System.out.println()` in productive EJB code!

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void a()
{
    System.out.println("+++ a()");
    System.out.println("TX status is " + getTXStatus());
    b();
    System.out.println("TX status is " + getTXStatus());
    System.out.println("--- a()");
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void b()
{
    System.out.println("+++ b()");
    System.out.println("TX status is " + getTXStatus());
    System.out.println("--- b()");
}
```

4 - now we may invoke `a()` and then `b()` from some client:

```
String beanName = "ejb:EJB3/MOD3//SagMalWas!de.treufuss.ejb3project.client.HelloWorldRemote";
HelloWorldBIF bif = HelloWorldBIF.class.cast(jndiContext.lookup(beanName));
bif.a();
bif.b();
```

which yields the following output in servers console:

```
12:58:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) +++ a()
12:58:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) TX status is STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
12:58:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) +++ b()
12:58:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) TX status is STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
12:58:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) --- b()
12:58:33,124 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) TX status is STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
12:58:33,124 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) --- a()

12:58:33,127 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 4) +++ b()
12:58:33,128 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 4) TX status is STATUS_ACTIVE
12:58:33,128 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 4) --- b()
```

Which proves that no transaction is started for invocation of `b()` from `a`

**Addendum**

You may force creation of a new transaction by invoking the `b()` method via beans business interface from EJB context. To do that...

1 - Inject EJB context as resource

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;
```

2 - Invoke `b()` method via business interface:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void a()
{
    System.out.println("+++ a()");
    System.out.println("TX status is " + getTXStatus());
    // Direct invocation is treated as POJMC (plain old java method call 
    b();
    // Indirect invocation via EJB context
    HelloWorldLocal thisBean = ctx.getBusinessObject(HelloWorldLocal.class);
    thisBean.b();
    System.out.println("TX status is " + getTXStatus());
    System.out.println("--- a()");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No transaction will be started. This is treated as internal method and is associated with current transaction. Since you `a()` method declares `NOT_SUPPORTED` transaction attribute, there will be no transaction created during invocation of methods `a()` and `b()`. Transaction attributes are respected, when **Client** calls the method, so if some component will call `testBean.b()` then new transaction will be created regardless, whether there already was transaction present or not.