# What's a clean, standard way to get multiple transactions in an EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, bulk, transactional

I have a `batchEdit(List<E> entity)` that calls an `edit(E entity)` function in a loop, while each edit() has it's own transaction so that failed edits don't rollback the good edits. I currently have it implemented like so:

**Option 1**

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement( value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER )
public class Service<E> {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute( value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW )
    public E edit( E entity ) {
       //edit code
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> bulkEdit( List<E> entities ) {
       for(E entity : entities){
          //case 1: Regular edit, Does not create a new transaction!
          //edit(entity);

          //case 2: Hacky edit, creates a new transaction
          context.getBusinessObject( Service.class ).editPersistNulls( entity );
       }
    }
}
```

According to [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427452/ejb-transactions-in-local-method-calls), The `@TransactionAttribute` is ignored in my case 1 because it doesn't cross any EJB boundaries, so `batchEdit()` calls `edit()` as if it wasn't annotated. Using the `context.getBusinessObject()` function in case 2 to grab a reference of the bean causes the TransactionManagement annotation to work, but it seems really weird to go through all of that.

**Option 2**

The other option I have is to change to bean managed transactions:

```
@TransactionManagement( value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN )
```

But then I would lose the "JPA Magic" and have to manage the transactions everywhere. I don't think other people on my team would want to go through that, so if there's a better or standard way to do this, any insight is appreciated.

We are using OpenJPA and EJBs, but we are trying to stay close to the JPA standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that "hacky" is in the eye of the beholder. `context.getBusinessObject` exists precisely so that you can do this kind of thing.

The alternative is to use a second class:

```
@Stateless
public class BulkService<E> {

    @EJB
    private Service<E> service;

    public List<E> bulkEdit( List<E> entities ) {
       for(E entity : entities) {
           service.editPersistNulls( entity );
       }
    }

}
```

Beware of large entity lists though, as your encompassing transaction can time out.

If you're using a Java EE 7 compliant server implementation then consider using the [JSR-352 Batch Applications](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352) support.

Comment: Interesting. We ended up going with the getBusinessObject solution; the only annoying part about that is that it needs the interface of the bean, not the bean's class itself. Passing the bean's class itself outputs a "Component has no such interface: <Bean's Class>", whereas passing in the interface it implements works.

Comment: If you eliminate the interfaces altogether then you can use the class name. Only use an interface on an EJB if you're planning a bunch of different implementations, which is not very often.

Comment: I will run that by my team. We had interfaces for potential testing that we haven't done yet, but passing in the interface is going to be a big refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can just inject EJB in self.

```
@Stateless
public class Service<E> {

    @EJB
    private Service<E> self;

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void edit(E entity) {
        // ...
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void bulkEdit(List<E> entities) {
        for (E entity : entities) {
           self.edit(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Better would be to make it `@Asynchronous`. It's faster.

```
@Stateless
public class Service<E> {

    @EJB
    private Service<E> self;

    public void edit(E entity) {
        // ...
    }

    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void asyncEdit(E entity) {
        // ...
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void bulkEdit(List<E> entities) {
        for (E entity : entities) {
           self.asyncEdit(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

It also keeps the original `edit()` method free from potentially unwanted `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction attribute as it might be called from other services which of course should stay in same transaction. For `@Asynchronous` it makes more sense to require a new transaction on every call.

Comment: What will happen, when i call the asynchronous method twice (or even more often) in short terms. Are the invokations stacked until an overflow occures?

Comment: One last question. You use REQUIRED_NEW. Since the calling function has NOT_SUPPORTED wouldn't the REQUIRED attribute be the same?

Comment: @kaiser Nope. It's not called on the same instance. I guess you need to take a step back and learn how EJBs actually work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25514361