# Making an independent call in nested @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I'm trying to make an independent call inside a method with transactional hook with following details :

```
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "tenantTransactionManager", isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) 
    void method1(){
    //business logic 1
    metohd2();
    //business logic 2
    }

    method2(){
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization( new TransactionSynchronization() {
                @Override
                public void afterCommit( boolean readOnly ) {
                      //businessLogic to be done after commit
                }
       });
    }
```

```
**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:**
```

1. Transactions in method 1 should rollback is any exception occurs
2. Transactions in method 2 should commit in any situation

Answer (score 0):

To run method2 in a separate transaction you have to do 2 things:

1. Move method2 to another class (EJB)
2. Annotate method2 with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

Moving it another class (EJB) because of:
See: [EJB Transactions in local method-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427452/ejb-transactions-in-local-method-calls)

Your app container (like Payara) will automatically create transactions for all methods in your @Stateless class / EJB, as if they are all annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED).

Also see: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/transactions004.html